# Extract substring using regex shell

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a string that contains multiple ocurrences in the way:

```
element 1 tag1{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},tag2{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},.. 
element 2 tag1{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},tag2{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},..
```

I want to extract using shell all the fields1, of the tag1 of all the elements

my try:

```
sed -n "s/.*\"tag1\":{\"fiel1\":\"\(.*\),\"fiel2\".*/\1/gp"
```

I am obtaining just the final one not all of them.

EDIT: The problem is that the whole text is in one single string and the regex just get me one cocurrence.

Thanks

Comment: You should generally not be using regex to parse structured data.  If you can massage this into JSON or XML, there are plenty of tools to take you from there.

Comment: i supect the text sample is missing the quote around tag1 and also : or your sed will never found something

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
sed 's/\(.*tag1{field1:"\)\([^"]*\)\(".*\)/\2/g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/tag1\{field1:\"([^\"]*)".*/$1/g' your_file
```

Or

```
awk -F":|," '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/.*[[:space:]]\{1,\}tag1{field1:"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/gp' YourFile
```

based on text sample

```
element 1 tag1{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},tag2{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},.. 
element 2 tag1{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},tag2{field1:"text",field2:"text"...},..
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}'
```

or to make sure its only extracted for lines with that `field1`

```
awk -F\" '/field1/ {print $2}'
```